# Nested JSON output to HTML table

Tags: html, json, flask

I'm trying to convert this nested json output into a html table :

```
{
  "language":"en",
  "retrieved_url":"https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/1986/1986canlii46/1986canlii46.html?autocompleteStr=r%20v%20oakes&autocompletePos=1",
  "semantic_roles":[
    {
      "action":{
        "normalized":"be charge",
        "text":"was charged",
        "verb":{
          "tense":"past",
          "text":"charge"
        }
      },
      "object":{
        "text":"with unlawful possession of a narcotic for the purpose of trafficking, contrary to s. 4(2) of the Narcotic Control Act"
      },
      "sentence":"\u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 Respondent was charged with unlawful possession of a narcotic for the purpose of trafficking, contrary to s. 4(2) of the Narcotic Control Act, but was convicted only of unlawful possession.",
      "subject":{
        "text":"Respondent"
      }
    },
```

The output should look like this (I only want the subject[text], action[text], object[text]) as columns:

```
| Subject    | Action      | Object                       |
|------------|-------------|------------------------------|
| Respondent | was charged | with unlawful possession ... |
|            |             |                              |
|            |             |                              |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Your JSON is not correctly formatted , i have did this below

-> 1) Extract all the data you want to show in variables from JSON as below

-> 2) Pass to the template to show them in table format , you can refer this for creating table [link for table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro)

make sure structure is as:

```
--templates
   --index.html
--app.py
```

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def test():
    data = {
        "language": "en",
        "retrieved_url": "https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/1986/1986canlii46/1986canlii46.html?autocompleteStr=r%20v%20oakes&autocompletePos=1",
        "semantic_roles": [
            {
                "action": {
                    "normalized": "be charge",
                    "text": "was charged",
                    "verb": {
                        "tense": "past",
                        "text": "charge"
                    }
                },
                "object": {
                    "text": "with unlawful possession of a narcotic for the purpose of trafficking, contrary to s. 4(2) of the Narcotic Control Act"
                },
                "sentence": "\u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 \u00a0\u00a0 Respondent was charged with unlawful possession of a narcotic for the purpose of trafficking, contrary to s. 4(2) of the Narcotic Control Act, but was convicted only of unlawful possession.",
                "subject": {
                    "text": "Respondent"
                }
            }]}
    action_text = data['semantic_roles'][0]['action']['text']
    object_text = data['semantic_roles'][0]['object']['text']
    subject_text = data['semantic_roles'][0]['subject']['text']
    return render_template('index.html', action_text=action_text, object_text=object_text, subject_text=subject_text)


if(__name__) == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

### index.html

*added style's for better visual

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Object</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ subject_text }}</td>
            <td>{{ action_text }}</td>
            <td>{{ object_text }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: glad i could help you :) , please upvote if you find it helpful